# How to write out the deployed git revision to a file in Capistrano

Tags: git, capistrano

I use Capistrano to deploy my rails app.  How can I write out the git revision being deployed to public_html/revision.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest commit ID with the log command and then redirect it to your file:

```
git --no-pager log -1 --pretty=format:%H > public_html/revision.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else has to do this:

```rb
    namespace :deploy do
      # ...

      desc "Write the current version to public_html/revision.txt"
      task :write_revision, :except => { :no_release => true } do
        run "cd #{latest_release}; git rev-parse HEAD > #{latest_release}/public/revision.txt"
      end

      # ...
    end

    after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:write_revision"
```

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my deploy.rb:

```
execute "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > public/revision.txt"
execute `"git log --oneline -1 >> public/revision.txt"`
```

Then in my internal admin page I have:

```
File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/revision.txt")
```

You can put in in Rails.root instead of public if you want.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a new feature that was added since the original question was asked, but Capistrano already creates a `REVISION` file in the app root. You can just copy this over. Here's what I have:

```rb
      desc "Write the current version to public/revision.txt"
      task :write_revision do
        on roles(:app, :api) do
          execute :cp, "#{fetch(:release_path)}/REVISION #{fetch(:release_path)}/public/revision.txt"
        end
      end
      after "deploy:finished", "deploy:write_revision"
```